# Setup Outlook rule to move an email to a folder after 14 days

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I have emails in my Outlook inbox that I want to keep for a while, so they are still visible.
After a period of time (say, 14 days) I want them moved to another folder, `storage`.

**Can this be done with rules?**

Notes:

1. As of now, I setup a rule to *Move a copy to folder `storage`*. But I am missing the deletion-after-14-days part.
2. In gmail, I could do that via apps scripting, with a script that runs every day. Moreover, since gmail uses labels instead of folders, I didn't have to move a copy, but simply add the label `storage` to the same email. 14 days later my script removed the label `Inbox` from the email.

**EDIT**:

As per comment by @squillman, it might be possible with VBA.
I guess this may be an interesting add-on.

Comment: I've never seen a (native) scheduler for Outlook rules, only as they arrive or as you send.  Something could probably be done with an add-in or in VBA, though.

Comment: You can do that automatically, but only to the Archive folder ([link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5238-outlook-move-items-older-than.html)), if that helps.

Comment: @harrymc - That is interesting, but I am not sure it can be combined with what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that automatically, but only to the Archive folder.
This option is called "AutoArchive" and is fully described in the article
[How to move items older than n days/weeks/months in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5238-outlook-move-items-older-than.html)

To fully answer your question requires a VBA macro.
You will find such VBA macros in the article
[Macro to Move Aged Email Messages](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/macro-move-aged-mail/), to use with a MAPI email server.
The macro itself is quoted below, but the article contains several variants:

- VBA Macro to check the default Inbox for email older that 7 days
  and move them to a sub-folder of the Inbox, called `Old`.
- Macro to move the messages to a new data file.
- Macro to move messages that were replied to or forwarded.

The article ends with an explanation of how to use macros.

The first of the above variants is quoted below.
You will need to change the `7` to `14`, and you may change the `Old`
name of the sub-folder.

```
Sub MoveAgedMail()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim lngMovedItems As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intDateDiff As Integer
    Dim strDestFolder As String
    
    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    ' use a subfolder under Inbox
    Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.Folders("Old")

    For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
        DoEvents
        If objVariant.Class = olMail Then
            
             intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)
             
            ' I'm using 7 days, adjust as needed. 
            If intDateDiff > 7 Then

              objVariant.Move objDestFolder
              
              'count the # of items moved
               lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Display the number of items that were moved.
    MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s)."
Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a rule as such (I have never had this working either) but in Office Outlook 365 (maybe in others) you can setup a retention period in the folder for emails (but sadly not for two weeks unless you can figure out how to add custom retentions). My system seems to be locked down but yours might not be as much.

You Can access it here:
[image: Outlook email retention]

Comment: This might be useful, but there are some things I still don't see...
Could you clarify where is "here" (in addition to the screen capture)? 
Where in the ribbon is the icon located? 
Note that Retention applied to folders or email items may be in different places.
The way I see this can work is:
1. Setup email Rule E1 for moving *a copy* to the target folder.
2. Setup a retention rule R1 to delete *from Inbox* after a certain period of time (if customizable, much better). The essential point is that R1 should match E1, so it affects the same emails... Can this be done?

Comment: The icon circled in red may depend on the Version of outlook you have (not specified in post). I am running Office 365 and have the default ribbon (simplified - it's called "Assign Policy" in classic). You might have modified your ribbon too which then only you can answer where you might have moved it too, so you might need to do some digging.

I have applied this to multiple different folders with different retention periods... some are 7 days, and some are 30 days. I use it for log files of backups or reports that I don't need to archive/keep hold of. Otherwise not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, only one of the two features you mentioned can be implemented. For moving the emails to a folder, you can create a rule as you have done. For moving them after 14 days, as harrymc mentioned, we can try to auto-archive.